# 2d array ascending bubblesort java

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, bubble-sort

I am trying to implement bubble sort on a 2D array to put the rows in ascending order, but it is only moving the first item. How can I fix this?

```
for(int i = 0; i<differencearray.length; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j<differencearray[i].length-1; j++){
            if(differencearray[i][j]>differencearray[i][j+1]){
                int temp = differencearray[i][j];
                differencearray[i][j] = differencearray[i][j+1];
                differencearray[i][j+1] = temp;
                }
        }
    }
```

The input is:

```
2147483647 15 9 13 24 

15 2147483647 18 16 17 

9 18 2147483647 12 27 

13 16 12 2147483647 25 

24 17 27 25 2147483647
```

The output is:

```
15 9 13 24 2147483647 

15 18 16 17 2147483647

9 18 12 27 2147483647

13 12 16 25 2147483647 

17 24 25 27 2147483647
```

Any help would be great!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bubble sort is an `O(n^2)`  algorithm so you need 2 for loops for a single array.

If you have n arrays then you would need 3 for loops in order to sort all the rows.

Which makes it `O(n^2*m)` algorithm. ( where m is the amount of rows)

Soooo...

```
 for(int i = 0; i < rowCount; i++){
   for(int j = 0; j < colCount; j++){
     for(int k = 0; k < colCount; k++){
       if(differencearray[i][k]>differencearray[i][k+1]){
            int temp = differencearray[i][k];
            differencearray[i][k] = differencearray[i][k+1];
            differencearray[i][k+1] = temp;
       }

     }
   }
 }
```

Comment: gives me arrayindexoutofbounds exception

Comment: @KhushalChouhan One of your counts is incorrect then. Either rowCount or colCount is larger then the array you are using it with.

Answer (score 0):

Been messing around with this a bit myself...

The biggest difference that I've noticed is that your bubble sort only iterates through the matrix once. It needs to keep swapping elements until everything is sorted. To fix this you need a proper exit condition (it needs to continue iterating once there is nothing left to swap). Therefore, it helps to add a while loop with a boolean expression.

The turning point here is that ***if***, your if statement evaluates to false (there are no numbers left to swap) the while loop will end the program. Otherwise, the program will keep re-looping until the while condition is met. Finally, You will have a properly sorted matrix.

```
int differencearray[][] = {{2147483647, 15, 9, 13, 24}, 
                           {15, 2147483647, 18, 16, 17}, 
                           {9, 18, 2147483647, 12, 27}, 
                           {13, 16, 12, 2147483647, 25}, 
                           {17, 24, 25, 27, 2147483647}};
int temp;
// initializing a boolean
boolean unsorted = true;
while(unsorted == true) {
    // exit condition to break while
    unsorted = false;
    // row
    for(int i = 0; i < differencearray.length; i++) {
        // column
        for(int j = 0; j < differencearray.length - 1; j++) {
            // swapping values
            if(differencearray[i][j] > differencearray[i][j + 1]) {
            // keeps re-entering while if unsorted remains true
            unsorted = true;
            temp = differencearray[i][j + 1];
            differencearray[i][j + 1] = differencearray[i][j];
            differencearray[i][j] = temp;
            }
        System.out.println("INSIDE " + Arrays.deepToString(differencearray));
        }
    }
    System.out.println("OUTSIDE " + Arrays.deepToString(differencearray));  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

this code generated a 2D int array of random numbers in the range between 0 to 10. Would really be glad to receive your comments about it.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    arraySorter();
}


public static void arraySorter(){

    int[][] storeArray = new int[4][4];

    for (int i = 0; i <4 ; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j <4 ; j++) {
            int randomNumber = (int) (10 * Math.random());
            storeArray[i][j] = randomNumber;
        }
    }
    System.out.println("========================================");
    System.out.println("The generated Array before sorting is : ");

    for (int[] row : storeArray) {
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(row));
    }

    boolean unsorted = true;
    while(unsorted == true) {

        unsorted = false;

        for(int i = 0; i < storeArray.length; i++) {
            for(int j = 0; j < storeArray.length - 1; j++) {
                if(storeArray[i][j] > storeArray[i][j + 1]) {
                    unsorted = true;
                    int temp = storeArray[i][j + 1];
                    storeArray[i][j + 1] = storeArray[i][j];
                    storeArray[i][j] = temp;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    System.out.println("========================================");
    System.out.println("The sorted Array before sorting is : ");
    for (int[] row : storeArray) {
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(row));
    }
}
```